# PySpark logistic regression missing method

Tags: python, pyspark, logistic-regression

I am new to `Pyspark`. I am using logistic regression API. I followed some tutorials and worked this way :

```
from pyspark.ml.classification import LogisticRegression

train, test = df.randomSplit([0.80, 0.20], seed = some_seed)

LR = LogisticRegression(featuresCol = 'features', labelCol = 'label', maxIter=some_iter)
LR_model = LR.fit(train)
```

When I call

```
trainingSummary = LR_model.summary
trainingSummary.roc
```

I get

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-319-bf79768ab64e> in <module>()
      1 trainingSummary = LR_model.summary
      2 
----> 3 trainingSummary.roc

AttributeError: 'LogisticRegressionTrainingSummary' object has no attribute 'roc'
```

Someone has an idea ?

Comment: According to the doc "LogisticRegressionTrainingSummary provides a summary for a LogisticRegressionModel. In the case of binary classification, certain additional metrics are available, e.g. ROC curve. See BinaryLogisticRegressionTrainingSummary" Are you using binary classification?

Comment: @smishra thank you for your response. But I don't understand this, do you mean that  in my case `trainingSummary` should have a `roc` method ?

Comment: Yes it should have if you are using binary classification. What version of Spark/SparkML are you using?